# EditText's cursor horizontally

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to have the cursor of an EditText horizontally disposed and not vertically? I would like to have it like in the following image:

[image: horizontal cursor]

I have read some topics were people play with the android:textCursorDrawable, but I need it to style it for Android < 3.0. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I am adding the xml of the EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/id"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_bottom_cursor" />
```

Comment: Use android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/your_cursor_drawable"

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a Cursor drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size 
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="1dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#000000" />
    <padding 
        android:top="-20sp"
        android:bottom="1sp" />


</shape>
```

or however you like.
2) `android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable"`
But this only works with Honeycomb or higher...
[image: Success]

Comment: @iyoon maybe Im doing something wrong, but on new devices I dont see the cursor and on devices with android 2.3.6 I see the same cursor as always. I have put the layout of the activity that contains the EditText in the folder layout-v11 and the custom drawable in the drawable-xhdpi folder. I also added the textCursorDrawable and the cursorVisible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Custom drawable should be placed in the `drawable` folder, with no dpi specified.

Comment: Still no luck. I updated my question, just in case that helps :P

Comment: I added a solution for 3.0 or higher, I will look for an answer for lower. Cheers.

Comment: That is really kind of you, let me know if you find something :D

Comment: Sorry, but as I stated in the question, I need a solution that is valid for < 3.0. I did give you a vote up because I think is a good answer for android > 3.0, but I am gonna leave it open in case someone can solve it :)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar , but I did not found a solution :( only one idea I had found was to set cursorVisible to false

```
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

then dynamically append char `_` to end of edittext, a set blinking animation to end of

```
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
anim.setStartOffset(20);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
lastChar.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Thanks! If I am not able to make jyoon's approach work, I will use your workaround :)

Comment: but the question is, was @AlvaroSantisteban able to make it work ? :D

Comment: There is a serious flaw in your answer; if you type while there is a underscore_, what you type will appear after it, breaking the input.

Comment: @jyoon why ? i would just add addTextChangedListener to move understore to end of the file when user type something ...

Comment: @MatejSpili Sorry, I should have added it :)

Comment: @jyoon But it wont work anyway ... because you can startAnimation only on the whole view :) so my solution is bad :)

Comment: @MatejSpili can you find a way to make my edited answer work in Honeycomb lower devices?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example on how I implemented this screen:

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/line"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#777777" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

Horizontal Line

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size android:width="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#9C27B0"/>
    <padding
        android:top="-47sp"
        android:bottom="-5sp"
        android:left="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

It's necessary to update the padding of the Horizontal Line if you change the height & width of the EditText